# Can an embedded cocos2d-js app call back out to c++?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm researching the possibility of using cocos2d-js by embedding it as a view inside an existing iOS app. In order to make this work, I'm going to need 2-way communication between cocos2d and the surrounding application.

After some initial investigation, I have determined that it is possible to call **in** to cocos using `ScriptingCore`:

```
ScriptingCore* sc = ScriptingCore::getInstance();
jsval outVal;
sc->evalString("function()", &outVal);
```

My question, then, is around doing the reverse. It is possible to (e.g. in response to user input) call back out of cocos2d-js to C++? Ideally, there would be a way to register a callback with `ScriptingCore` which could be invoked from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be done, but I have not tried myself, nor can I find a good and concise example.
All I can do is point you at [SuperSuraccoon's Bluetooth example](http://www.supersuraccoon-cocos2d.com/2014/03/02/a-simple-solution-on-implementing-bluetooth-multiplayer-with-cocos2d-html5-jsbinding-cocos2d-x-gamekit/) and it's [git page](https://github.com/supersuraccoon/JSBBlueTooth), which apparently does both ways communication between C++ and JS code.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the key is to call [JS_DefineFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS_DefineFunction). The SpiderMonkey JSAPI reference has a lot of good information on how to do this kind of thing, actually, I just wasn't looking in the right place before.